# Swift count time untill button is pressed

Tags: swift, datetime, time

I would like to count the time from when the view as Loaded untill the user presses a button. I also need it to count miliseconds so it would be precise.

Comment: Sure, what code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a timer

```
fileprivate var timer: Timer?
var seconds: Int = 0

func runTimer() { 
     timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: (#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateTimer() {
    seconds += 1  
}
```

Now its just a matter on when you start the timer.
Options : `viewDidLoad , viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear`

Then on the IBActions of the button pressed , you capture the seconds passed and stop the timer.

```
timer?.invalidate()
timer = nil
```

Comment: how can I stop the timer?

Comment: updated , see the answer

Comment: Iv'e changed it into milliseconds, how can I make the number a little less longer (in ex. 1.33699999999996 seconds to 1.336 seconds)

Comment: you can change the interval , now its every 1 second. Change it to a smaller interval for example and then adjust the counter to add the same amount.